# How to set a custom Index.html in CPANEL?

Tags: php, html

I just wanna ask something.

I am using cuccfree.com for my free webhosting and Vista Panel for my CPanel.

in my CPANEL i have a folder named districtfive.cu.cc and it contains all of my files.

When Im trying to browse my link it always shows a list of Folders and Files of Index of.

My question is that how can I prevent to show all of that folders and instead show my website? I mean if i browse districtfive.cu.cc it will automatically open my Admin.php.

Does it have to do with:
Index Manager(My CPanel doesnt have that)
.htaccess(I dont know how to use it but i try but still noting happens.)

any suggestions or answer is highly appreciated. TY

Answer (score 1):

Create an .htaccess file. Inside of this:

```
DirectoryIndex Admin.php index.php index.html
```

Seems like you're not using the default `index.php`. Also, any reason you're not using the default `index.php` nomenclature most people have come to expect?

Answer (score 0):

Rename admin.php as index.php. It will automatically open your site with url 'districtfive.cu.cc'.